# Safari can’t connect to the server local host

Tags: macos, tomcat, safari, server, localhost

Whenever I start Tomcat, and open http://localhost:8080 I get the following error.

**Safari can’t open the page “localhost:8080” because Safari can’t connect to the server *“localhost”*.**

It used to work before today. All I did earlier today was block some websites using the host files, but I restored them back again, and now it looks like this.

```
#  
##  
# Host Database  
#  
#  
# localhost is used to configure the lookback interface  
# when the system is booting. Do not change this entry.  
##  
127.0.0.1        localhost    
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost    
::1         localhost  
fe80::1%lo0  localhost
```

If I start and stop the server using Eclipse, it works. But localhost can’t connect to server using Safari or Google Chrome either..

I know there are a lot of similar questions, but none of them seemed to help.

*Thanks a lot in advance!*

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:80  Use.. Its also open your localhost ... ..

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar I’m still getting the same error. Safari can’t open the page “127.0.0.1” because Safari can’t connect to the server “127.0.0.1”.

Comment: okk wait..  ....

Comment: xampp Use kar rahe ho ..  ??

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar no?!